# Debugging a Map backed by an AVL tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, maps, avl-tree

This is one of three trees I am using to parse text and print out every unique word, the line numbers it appears on, and the number of times it appears.  I have already used a hash and tree map and have both of them working correctly.  My instructor said that we need to use an AVL tree for the third map and gave us code.  This is where I am unsure where to go.  I will include the method that creates/fills the AVL map as well as the AVL map class. If further code is needed, I will gladly include it.

```
    public void avlMap(String fileName){

    //try/catch block to check for invalid file name
    try{
        //creates new bufferedreader object for input file
        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        //creates new treeMap object named avlMap
        Map avlMap = new AvlMap();
        String oneLine;

        //Read the words and add them to the avlMap
        for (int lineNum = 1; (oneLine = inFile.readLine()) != null; lineNum++){
            String delims = " !@#$%{}[]/^&*,.()-;:\'\"\t";
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(oneLine, delims);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
                String word = st.nextToken();
                WordStats stats = (WordStats) avlMap.get(word);

                //if WordStats is empty/doesnt exist,
                //if exists, adds line numbers into a WordStats in the value
                //...field for the int's respective key
                if (stats == null){
                    stats = new WordStats();
                    avlMap.put(word, stats);
                }
                //WordStats already exists for the word
                //calls addOccurrence method and adds the line number
                stats.addOccurrence(new Integer(lineNum));  
            }
        }

        //creates a new iterator object to iterate entries
        Iterator itr = avlMap.entrySet().iterator();

        //runs printEntry for each key in the treeMap
        while (itr.hasNext()){
            printEntry((Map.Entry) itr.next());
        }
    }
        //the file name used wasn't able to be reached
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

AvlMap class.  I know it is quite lengthy, but the methods seem to be pretty much the same as the rest of the map classes I have been using.

```
    public class AvlMap <AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>> implements Map 
    {
    //construct the tree
    public AvlMap( ){
        root = null;
    }

    //inserts object into the map
    public void insert( AnyType x, AnyType y ){
        root = insert( x, y, root );
    }

    //removes the key from the map
    public void remove( AnyType x ){
        root = remove( x, root );
    }

    //internal method to remove from a subtree
    private AvlNode<AnyType> remove( AnyType x, AvlNode<AnyType> t ){
        if( t == null )
            return t;   // Item not found; do nothing

        int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.key );

        if( compareResult < 0 )
            t.left = remove( x, t.left );
        else if( compareResult > 0 )
            t.right = remove( x, t.right );
        else if( t.left != null && t.right != null ) // Two children
        {
            t.key = findMin( t.right ).key;
            t.right = remove( t.key, t.right );
        }
        else
            t = ( t.left != null ) ? t.left : t.right;
        return balance( t );
    }

    //returns the smallest item in the tree
    public AnyType findMin( ){
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            throw new UnderflowException("Error" );
        return findMin( root ).key;
    }

    //returns the largest item in the tree
    public AnyType findMax( ){
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            throw new UnderflowException("Error" );
        return findMax( root ).key;
    }

    //finds the provided item in the tree
    public boolean contains( AnyType key ){
        return contains( key, root );
    }

    //make the tree empty
    public void makeEmpty( ){
        root = null;
    }

    //tests if the tree is empty
    public boolean isEmpty( ){
        return root == null;
    }

    //prints the tree in sorted order
    public void printTree( ){
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            System.out.println( "Empty tree" );
        else
            printTree( root );
    }

    private static final int ALLOWED_IMBALANCE = 1;

    // Assume t is either balanced or within one of being balanced
    private AvlNode<AnyType> balance( AvlNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return t;

        if( height( t.left ) - height( t.right ) > ALLOWED_IMBALANCE )
            if( height( t.left.left ) >= height( t.left.right ) )
                t = rotateWithLeftChild( t );
            else
                t = doubleWithLeftChild( t );
        else
        if( height( t.right ) - height( t.left ) > ALLOWED_IMBALANCE )
            if( height( t.right.right ) >= height( t.right.left ) )
                t = rotateWithRightChild( t );
            else
                t = doubleWithRightChild( t );

        t.height = Math.max( height( t.left ), height( t.right ) ) + 1;
        return t;
    }

    //checks the trees balance
    public void checkBalance( ){
        checkBalance( root );
    }

    //driver for checking the trees balance
    private int checkBalance( AvlNode<AnyType> t ){
        if( t == null )
            return -1;

        if( t != null )
        {
            int hl = checkBalance( t.left );
            int hr = checkBalance( t.right );
            if( Math.abs( height( t.left ) - height( t.right ) ) > 1 ||
                    height( t.left ) != hl || height( t.right ) != hr )
                System.out.println( "OOPS!!" );
        }

        return height( t );
    }

    //method to insert into a subtree
    private AvlNode<AnyType> insert( AnyType key, AnyType value, AvlNode<AnyType> t ){
        if( t == null )
            return new AvlNode<>( key, value, null, null );

        int compareResult = key.compareTo( t.key );

        if( compareResult < 0 )
            t.left = insert( key, value,t.left );
        else if( compareResult > 0 )
            t.right = insert( key, value, t.right );
        else
            ;  // Duplicate; do nothing
        return balance( t );
    }

    //returns the smallest item in a subtree
    private AvlNode<AnyType> findMin( AvlNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return t;

        while( t.left != null )
            t = t.left;
        return t;
    }

    //finds the largest item in a subtree
    private AvlNode<AnyType> findMax( AvlNode<AnyType> t ){
        if( t == null )
            return t;

        while( t.right != null )
            t = t.right;
        return t;
    }

    //finds an item in a subtree
    private boolean contains( AnyType x, AvlNode<AnyType> t ){
        while( t != null ){
            int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.key );

            if( compareResult < 0 )
                t = t.left;
            else if( compareResult > 0 )
                t = t.right;
            else
                return true;    // Match
        }
        return false;   // No match
    }

    //prints the subtree in sorted order
    private void printTree( AvlNode<AnyType> t ){
        if( t != null ){
            printTree( t.left );
            System.out.println( t.key + " " + t.value );
            printTree( t.right );
        }    
    }

    //returns the height of node t or -1 if null
    private int height( AvlNode<AnyType> t ){
        return t == null ? -1 : t.height;
    }

    //rotates tree node with left child
    private AvlNode<AnyType> rotateWithLeftChild( AvlNode<AnyType> k2 ){
        AvlNode<AnyType> k1 = k2.left;
        k2.left = k1.right;
        k1.right = k2;
        k2.height = Math.max( height( k2.left ), height( k2.right ) ) + 1;
        k1.height = Math.max( height( k1.left ), k2.height ) + 1;
        return k1;
    }

    //rotates tree node with right child
    private AvlNode<AnyType> rotateWithRightChild( AvlNode<AnyType> k1 ){
        AvlNode<AnyType> k2 = k1.right;
        k1.right = k2.left;
        k2.left = k1;
        k1.height = Math.max( height( k1.left ), height( k1.right ) ) + 1;
        k2.height = Math.max( height( k2.right ), k1.height ) + 1;
        return k2;
    }

    //double rotates tree node.  first left child with its right child, then 
    //...node k3 with new left child.
    private AvlNode<AnyType> doubleWithLeftChild( AvlNode<AnyType> k3 ){
        k3.left = rotateWithRightChild( k3.left );
        return rotateWithLeftChild( k3 );
    }

    //double rotates tree node.  first right child with its left child, then
    //...node k1 with new right child
    private AvlNode<AnyType> doubleWithRightChild( AvlNode<AnyType> k1 ){
        k1.right = rotateWithLeftChild( k1.right );
        return rotateWithRightChild( k1 );
    }

    private static class AvlNode<AnyType>{
            // Constructors
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        AvlNode( AnyType theKey, AnyType theValue ){
            this( theKey, theValue, null, null );
        }

        AvlNode( AnyType theKey, AnyType theValue, AvlNode<AnyType> lt, AvlNode<AnyType> rt ){
            key  = theKey;
            value = theValue;
            left     = lt;
            right    = rt;
            height   = 0;
        }

        AnyType           key;      // The data in the node
        AnyType           value;
        AvlNode<AnyType>  left;         // Left child
        AvlNode<AnyType>  right;        // Right child
        int               height;       // Height
    }

    //trees root
    private AvlNode<AnyType> root;

    //implemented methods for AvlTreeMap
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        makeEmpty();    
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        contains ((AnyType)key);

        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        contains ((AnyType)value);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Set entrySet() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(Object key) {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Set keySet() {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
        insert ((AnyType)key, (AnyType) value);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map m) {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Object remove(Object key) {
        remove ((AnyType)key);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection values() {
        return null;
    }
    }
```

Here is my WordStats class that saves everything into a set and keeps occurrance.

```
    import java.util.SortedSet;
    import java.util.TreeSet;


    public class WordStats {
private int occurrences;
private SortedSet<Integer> lineNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();

public void addOccurrence(int lineNumber){
    occurrences++;
    lineNumbers.add(lineNumber);
}

public int getOccurrences(){
    return occurrences;
}

public SortedSet<Integer> getLines(){
    return lineNumbers;
}
    }
```

When I run the program, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.ClassCastException`:
>
> `java.lang.String` cannot be cast to `WordStats`
>
> at `driver1.avlMap(driver1.java:182)`
>
> at `driver1.main(driver1.java:36)`

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.  There are also not any compiler errors.

Comment: For future reference, try to construct a minimal test case. A lot of people who see that much code will just move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue, as mentioned in the stack trace, is that you are trying to cast an object of type `String` to something of type `WordStats`.  I think that this occurs in this line:

```
WordStats stats = (WordStats) avlMap.get(word);
```

So let's look at `avlMap.get(word)`.  This looks as follows:

```
@Override
public Object get(Object key) {
    return key;
}
```

So this is problematic - it looks like every time you try to do a lookup, you're just returning the key that you were trying to look up inside the map!  That would explain the casting error - you're passing in a `String` into `avlMap.get()`, which then returns it.  When you try casting it to a `WordStats`, you're getting an error because a `String` isn't a `WordStats`.

To fix this, I think you need your `get` method to actually do a search in the AVL tree and do a lookup.  I will leave this for you to complete yourself.  I would **strongly** suggest not trying to integrate your map into a larger program until you've tested it more thoroughly - having all of the logic to process words layered on top of a buggy AVL tree will make debugging extremely difficult, if not impossible.  Try writing some unit tests for your AVL tree to see whether it's working.  You could also consider swapping out your AVL tree map for a normal `TreeMap` in the interim to see if the driver code works.

As another note - you should **strongly** consider not implementing the raw type `Map` and instead implement `Map` parameterized over a key and value type.  This makes the interface way easier to use and would help catch the bug that you encountered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The other two maps I used were Tree and Hash maps.  This should get me going in the right direction.  I also noticed you deleted the last line in my post.  I understand a lot of people have problems with that, which is understandable.  If you would like me to follow through, just lmk.